# setDragImage Doesn't Work In Safari, But Works In Chrome (HTML Drag API)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use `.setDragImage` on an anchor element to customize its image when it is being dragged. For some reason, it works perfectly in Chrome but not in Safari. Here is an example:

```js
const drag = document.getElementById("drag");

const testEl = document.createElement("div");
testEl.innerText = "Drag Info";

drag.ondragstart = (event)=>{
  document.body.appendChild(testEl);
  
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(testEl, 0, 0);
  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    testEl.remove();
  }, 1);
};
```

```html
<a id="drag" href="javascript:console.log('clicked')">Drag Me</a>
```

Notice that when dragging, in Safari a special box with the link is displayed, while in Chrome it correctly says "Drag Info"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in order to add a drag image to an element you must set its `draggable` property equal to true.

E.g

```html
<a href="...">Link</a>
```

Should be

```html
<a href="..." draggable="true">Link</a>
```

Fixed example:

```js
const drag = document.getElementById("drag");

const testEl = document.createElement("div");
testEl.innerText = "Drag Info";

drag.ondragstart = (event)=>{
  document.body.appendChild(testEl);
  
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(testEl, 0, 0);
  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    testEl.remove();
  }, 1);
};
```

```html
<a draggable="true" id="drag" href="javascript:console.log('clicked')">Drag Me</a>
```